# Macro that follows a link and downloads the table into a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am a geologist working for a small oil company in Louisiana. I constitute our tech department, and unfortunately my experience with coding is quite limited. I have used very basic vba coding in the past, but I dont code that much in my daily job, so I have forgotten most of it.

The louisiana dnr keeps amazing records for every single oil well drilled in the state and all of these records are located at www.Sonris.com. Part of these records are the production records for each well. I would like to create a macro that follows a given url and downloads the table found on the URL (aka the production records). After it downloads the file, I would like it to put the table in a new sheet and then to name this sheet based on the well name.

I have fooled around with the retrieve data from web function, however I cannot make the function dynamic enough. I need the code to copy the hyperlink data found in a cell. Currently, the code just follows the hyperlink that I copy and paste while recording the macro.

Any help would be appreciated

Sincerely,
Josiah

Below is the code generated;

```
    Sub Macro2()
'
'     Macro2 Macro
' attempt with multiple well to look at code instead of 1 well
'

'
    Range("E27").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=159392" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=159392"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "1,11"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: How many wells are you looking to retrieve, where are the WSN numbers and do you want all of the tables or just a selection?

Comment: I would ideally like to do this for a whole field (so somewhere in the range of 300 wells). I just want to use 1 table in a selction of the tables.   What are WSN numbers?

Comment: I'm guessing the WSN is the *well serial number* as in `...?p_WSN=159392`.

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies. I thought that was a code. That does stand for well serial number. The serial number is in a column in the worksheet. So far I havent tried to use it in the code.

Comment: What does your code above do currently when run?  Does it work successfully for that particular `WSN=159392`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to piggy back on @Jeeped awesome solution, I added in the formating to delete and just have the LeaseUnit/Well/Production info left.  This assumes Casing table always follow the Production table

```
Option Explicit

Public Const csURL As String = "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=×WSN×"

Sub Gather_Well_Data()
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, w As Long, wsn As String, wb As Workbook, frow As String, lrow As String
    On Error GoTo Fìn
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False



    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WSNs")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For rw = 2 To lr
            .Cells(rw, 2) = 0
            For w = 1 To .Parent.Sheets.Count
                If .Parent.Sheets(w).Name = CStr(.Cells(rw, 1).Value) Then
                    .Parent.Sheets(w).Delete
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next w
            wsn = Replace(csURL, "×WSN×", .Cells(rw, 1).Value)
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wsn, ReadOnly:=True, addtomru:=False)

            frow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("LEASE\UNIT\WELL PRODUCTION", Range("A:A"), 0)
            lrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Casing", Range("A:A"), 0)
            lrow = lrow - 1
            frow = "A" & frow
            lrow = "K" & lrow
            Range(frow, lrow).Cut Range("Q1")
            Columns("A:P").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

            wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A3").Font.Size = 12
            wb.Sheets(1).Copy After:=.Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count)
            .Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count).Name = .Cells(rw, 1).Value
            wb.Close savechanges:=False
            Set wb = Nothing
            .Cells(rw, 2) = 1
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            .Parent.Save
        Next rw
        .Activate
    End With
Fìn:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

With all of the methods available to scrub external data, many users forget that you can open a web page full of tables with nothing more than a valid URL and File ► Open. I'm posting the code here but I will also supply a link to a working sample workbook that took ~ 2 minutes to gather the full web page data from 14 sequentially numbered WSN (*web serial number*) pages. Your own results may vary.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const csURL As String = "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=×WSN×"

Sub Gather_Well_Data()
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, w As Long, wsn As String, wb As Workbook
    On Error GoTo Fìn
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WSNs")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For rw = 2 To lr
            .Cells(rw, 2) = 0
            For w = 1 To .Parent.Sheets.Count
                If .Parent.Sheets(w).Name = CStr(.Cells(rw, 1).Value) Then
                    .Parent.Sheets(w).Delete
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next w
            wsn = Replace(csURL, "×WSN×", .Cells(rw, 1).Value)
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wsn, ReadOnly:=True, addtomru:=False)
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A3").Font.Size = 12
            wb.Sheets(1).Copy After:=.Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count)
            .Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count).Name = .Cells(rw, 1).Value
            wb.Close savechanges:=False
            Set wb = Nothing
            .Cells(rw, 2) = 1
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            .Parent.Save
        Next rw
        .Activate
    End With
Fìn:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The list of WSN identifiers are in the **WSNs** worksheet starting in column 2. Run the macro by tapping <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to open the **Macros** dialog and <kbd>Run</kbd> the *Gather_Well_Data* macro. When it is complete, you will have a workbook filled with worksheets identified by the WSNs similar to below.

[image: LA Well data]

The sample workbook is on my public DropBox at:

[LA_WSN_Data.xlsb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/LA_WSN_Data.xlsb)

Comment: Thanks so much for all the work youve done on this. I had a followup question. Is there a way to only download one table from the webpage instead of the entire well report? I am looking to automtically download the production data (the leaseunit/well production table on the webpage) and then plug it into a formatted workbook to automatically calculate some values my company is interested in.

Comment: @JosiahHulsey - Yes, it would be very possible with either Excel's Data ► Get External Data ► From Web page, an Internet Explorer object or even a Msxml.DOMDocument dom object but TBH, it would be easier to gather your 300 pages and delete everything you didn't want or collate what you actually wanted into one large data table or database.

Answer (score 1):

Jeeped's method rocks.+1

You can also issue `POST` requests against the API and write all the tables out as follows.

Note: I am writing each Well info one under the other but it is easy enough to put a Sheets.Add line in before the next API call and simply ensure each data write out uses the activesheet.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetWellInfo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, page As HTMLDocument, targetTable As HTMLTable, apiNumbers(), currNumber As Long
    Const PARAM1 As String = "p_apinum"
    Const BASESTRING As String = "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/"
    apiNumbers = Array(1708300502, 1708300503)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Cells.ClearContents
        For currNumber = LBound(apiNumbers) To UBound(apiNumbers)
            Set page = GetPage(BASESTRING & "cart_con_wellapi2", apiNumbers(currNumber), PARAM1)
            Set page = GetPage(BASESTRING & GetNextURL(page.body.innerHTML))
            Dim allTables As Object
            Set allTables = page.getElementsByTagName("table")

            For Each targetTable In allTables
                AddHeaders targetTable, GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 2, ws
                WriteTables targetTable, GetLastRow(ws, 1), ws
            Next targetTable

        Next currNumber
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetPage(ByVal url As String, Optional ByVal apiNumber As Long, Optional ByVal paramN As String = vbNullString) As HTMLDocument
    Dim objHTTP As Object, html As New HTMLDocument

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    Dim sBody As String
    If Not paramN = vbNullString Then sBody = paramN & "=" & apiNumber
    With objHTTP
        .SetTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        On Error Resume Next
        .send (sBody)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            If .Status = "200" Then
                html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                Set GetPage = html
            Else
                Debug.Print "HTTP " & .Status & " " & .statusText
                Exit Function
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Source & " " & Err.Description
            Exit Function
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

End Function

Public Function GetNextURL(ByVal inputString As String)
    GetNextURL = Replace$(Replace$(Split(Split(inputString, "href=")(1), ">")(0), Chr$(34), vbNullString), "about:", vbNullString)
End Function

Public Sub AddHeaders(ByVal hTable As Object, ByVal startRow As Long, ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long
    Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
    For Each header In headers
        columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
        ws.Cells(startRow, columnCounter) = header.innerText
    Next header
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTables(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    r = startRow
    With ActiveSheet
        Set tRow = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each tr In tRow
            Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            For Each td In tCell
                .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText
                c = c + 1
            Next td
            r = r + 1:  c = 1
        Next tr
    End With
End Sub
```